# Encrypt in java and Decrypt in C# and reverse

Tags: bouncycastle, encryption

I have read some topic for my title, so I can't use them to fix my problem. So, i open a new topic...
I want to create 2 functions Encrypt and Decrypt in java (for Android app) and C# (my server) using symmetric encryption

Client (java) : Encrypt(ClearText1, Key)=secret --> Server : Decrypt(secret,Key)=ClearText1
and
Server (java) : Encrypt(ClearText2, Key)=secret --> Client: Decrypt(secret,Key)=ClearText2

I have used BouncyCastle Library For java and C#, but the byte in java is -128..127, while the byte in C# is 0..255, have not negative data. So client and Server encryption and decryption is fail.

Please help me (or share me the library for my problem). Thank you!

Here the code in C#:
How to use them in java? Note the data type "byte" in C# and java in not match
(of course, encrypt and decrypt data with 2 following funcions is true)

```
>     public string _secretPhrase = "123abc456";
>     public string EncryptData(string plainText)
>     {
>         DES des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
>         des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
>         des.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
> 
>         des.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secretPhrase.Substring(0, 8));
>         des.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secretPhrase.Substring(0, 8));
> 
>         byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
>         byte[] resultBytes = des.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
> 
>         return Convert.ToBase64String(resultBytes);
>     }
> 
>     public string DecryptData(string encryptedText)
>     {
>         DES des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
>         des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
>         des.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
>         des.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secretPhrase.Substring(0, 8));
>         des.IV = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secretPhrase.Substring(0, 8));
> 
>         byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
>         byte[] resultBytes = des.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
> 
>         return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBytes);
>     }
```

Comment: That's a big library.  Either post your code or explain how you're using it.

Comment: Please edit your question.  Also, please post the code for both languages.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are using BouncyCastle.  That looks like stock .NET Framework cryptography code.  BouncyCastle uses naming conventions like DesEngine.

I recommend that you try using BouncyCastle for both [C#](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) and [Java](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html).  I'm not convinced the byte difference will be a practical problem.  The library should account for it correctly.

Also, single DES is now considered very weak.  There are [single day attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Chronology) against it on reasonable hardware, and it's no longer an approved standard.  Look at AES instead.

Finally, I'm not sure using the same key and IV are wise.  I'm not a cryptography expert, but using two distinct random numbers should be safer.

Comment: The code is not BouncyCastle, because it is fail when encrypt or decrypt with "byte" data type.

Comment: @black_star, post your BouncyCastle code (for both C# and Java if you have it).  I doubt the library simply can't encrypt byte arrays (that's the whole point of it).  Most likely, you have to correct your code.

Comment: the BouncyCastle is flexible, so can I compress them and send to you?

Comment: @black_star, no, post it in the question, or put it on something like [gist](https://gist.github.com/), then post the link. That way, everyone can help.